# Find the eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix as a function of angles

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

I have a problem which seems flawed to me.

> Consider the hermitian matrix M
>
> \begin{pmatrix}
>  a/2 & b^* \\ 
>  b & -a/2
>  \end{pmatrix}
>   with a>0 real and b complex.
>   Let $\theta$,$\phi$ be the two angles given by $\tan{\theta}$=$\frac{2|b|}{a}$ and $b=|b|e^{i\phi}$. Calculate the eigenvalues of M as a function of these angles and show that $v_1=(\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{-i\phi/2},\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{i\phi/2})^T$ and $v_2=(-\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{-i\phi/2}, \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{i\phi/2})^T$ are the corresponding eigenvectors and form an orthonormal system.

I calculated the eigenvalues to 
\begin{align}
\lambda_{1,2}=\pm|b|\sqrt{1+\cot^2{x}}
\end{align}
But no matter what I try, these eigenvalues do not correspond with the given eigenvectors. I also tried calculating the eigenvalues starting with the eigenvectors but that doesnt work, too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your calculation of the eigenvalue, but I still think the problem is not right.

The eigenvalues of $M$ are $\frac a2\pm |b|$. One then finds easily that a corresponding pair of eigenvectors is given by 
$$
(e^{-i\phi/2},-e^{i\phi/2})^T,\ \ (e^{-i\phi/2},e^{i\phi/2})^T. 
$$
The eigenspaces are spanned by each of these two vectors, so the supposed eigenvectors in the statement of the problem aren't eigenvectors (they are not scalar multiples of the above).

---

**Edit:** after the question has been changed, here is the new answer:

When $$M=\begin{bmatrix}a/2&\bar b\\ b&-a/2\end{bmatrix},$$
the eigenvalues are $$\pm|b|\,\left(1+\frac{a^2}{4|b|^2}\right)^{1/2}
=\pm|b|\,\left(1+\frac1{\tan^2\theta}\right)^{1/2}=\pm|b|\,\frac{(1+\tan^2\theta)^{1/2}}{\tan \theta}=\pm\,\frac{|b|}{\sin \theta}.
$$
If $(x,y)^T$ is an eigenvector for $|b|/\sin\theta$, then 
$$
\left(\frac a2-\frac{|b|}{\sin\theta}\right)x+\bar b\,y=0.
$$
That is, 
$$
\left(\frac{|b|}{\tan\theta}-\frac{|b|}{\sin\theta}\right)\,x+|b|\,e^{-i\phi}\,y=0.
$$
After multiplying by $\sin\theta\,e^{i\phi/2}/|b|$,
$$
(\cos\theta -1)\,e^{i\phi/2}\,x+\sin\theta\,e^{-i\phi/2}y=0.
$$
Using the half-angle formulas,
$$
-2\sin^2\frac\theta2\,e^{i\phi/2}\,x+2\sin\frac\theta2\,\cos\frac\theta2\,e^{-i\phi/2}\,y=0.
$$
And now, multiplying by $1/(2\sin\frac\theta2)$,
$$
-\sin\frac\theta2\,e^{i\phi/2}\,x+\cos\frac\theta2\,e^{-i\phi/2}\,y=0.
$$
Then 
$$(x,y)^T=(\cos\frac\theta2\,e^{-i\phi/2},\sin\frac\theta2e^{i\phi/2})^T$$
is an eigenvector for $|b|/\sin\theta$.

The computation for the other eigenvalue is very similar.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you. Sadly i made a mistake when typing the matrix. The last component should be $-a/2$ not $a/2$. Still I cant see how the given eigenvectors are supposed to be right for all angles theta. I just got to the result, that this is only true for $\theta=\pi/2$

Comment: Please see the edit.